# Title element doesn't work with Action Element in Manifest XML

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I am creating an add-in for Microsoft Word.

I am getting manifest validation error for `Title` element inside `Action` element.

[Microsoft Reference documentation for Action Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/manifest/action?view=office-js)

```
Error #1:
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'Action' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Title' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'. List of possible elements expected: 'TaskpaneId, SourceLocation' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.
  - Line: 54
  - Column: 22
```

Example:

```
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
       <Title resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Title" />  --> //Adding this line throws error 
       <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
       <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
   </Action>
```

Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator checks the order in which the XML elements appear.

Please use the code below:

```
   <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
      <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
      <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
       <Title resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Title" />  -->  
   </Action>
```